# Do the bonus quests for Companions' leaders end?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have become the Harbinger of the Companions. But I still keep getting "Talk to the leaders of the Companions for more work" in the miscellaneous quest journal. Does this ever end? Also as Harbinger of the Companions, why does it say talk to the "leader" of the Companions, am I not their head? I should be sending them on such little quests like "Rescue X from Y place".

Comment: `I should be sending them on such little quests like "Rescue X from Y place".` Totally! And as arch-mage, expel certain deserving wizards from the college!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, these quests do not end. These are simply due to the Radiant A.I., and never ending quests.

Also, as the Harbinger, you're not the leader, it would be better described as an adviser to the council of Companions.

Answer (score 2):

The Companions have not had a leader since Ysgrimor thousands of years before the game of Skyrim. Once Ysgrimor passed on nobody felt they could live up to Ysgrimor's title as Leader and thus was born The Harbinger. The harbinger is better described as a group advisor rather than a leader. As far as the quests, I have done at least 5 quests for each of the remaining "leaders" and I still get the quest. Everything I've read online says that there is no end to the quest. Hope this helps...

Answer (score -2):

The companions have no leader, they're an equal collective. Also, the missions never end.

Comment: You just rephrased the existing answer. Not very helpful..

Comment: Companions always had the leader and it is Harbinger. Kodlak was not Harbinger but adviser since last leader died and no one took the title of leader aka. Harbinger.

Answer (score -3):

Like Kodlak says, he's not their leader they are all equal he just kinda gives advice. And for the quests they never end but it's very easy money so it's not a bad thing.

Comment: Please try to avoid posting answers that simply re-state content from other existing answers. Feel free to add any additional relevant information that you feel is missing from those answers, however.